# Applying timezone to the timestamp in Python

Tags: python, time, timestamp, timezone

I have timezones in a format like this: "RTZ 2 (зима)"

This is Cyrillic as you can see. I need to apply this to the timestamp.

I know that the `pytz` module can create a `tz` subclass from the timezone name. However when I do:

```
try:
    t = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).astimezone(pytz.timezone("RTZ 2 (зима)"))

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: " + str(e))
```

I get this exception:

`Exception: 'RTZ 2 (зима)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

How can I convert this format "RTZ 2 (зима)" to the correct timezone recognized by `pytz`? Should I use another module which understands this name?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no.  You cannot convert a language-specific display string into a time zone identifier.  Display strings are not standardized.

The best approach is to track down the source of the data and ensure that [IANA TZ Database time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are used instead.

Alternatively, if you have a fixed dataset, then you could extract all of the distinct time zone display names and use them to create a mapping back to an identifier that will work with your specific dataset.

Answer (score 3):

In Python's pytz library, timezones are generally represented using strings like "Europe/Moscow" instead of "RTZ 2 (зима)".

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime


timestamp = 1628685962  # Replace with your timestamp
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")  # Use the correct timezone string
t = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).astimezone(tz)
print(t)
```

Comment: is there a library which i can use to convert this "RTZ 2 (зима)" to this "Europe/Moscow"  automatically?

Answer (score -1):

The problem looks like encoding. if you encode the string as utf-8 and decode again, it ensures that the Cyrillic characters are handled correctly.

```
tz_name = "RTZ 2 (зима)".encode("utf-8")
decoded_tz_name = tz_name.decode("utf-8")
timestamp = 1631366400
t = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=pytz.timezone(decoded_tz_name))
```